# iOS Save the top number from a label.

Tags: ios, uilabel

So I have this app that tracks your speed and altitude. I have a UILabel that shows the current speed you are at and the current altitude you are at. What I want to do is have a label that shows the max altitude and the max speed. So basically if you are running and your speed reaches 5 mph the max label will say 5 mph and then if you get to 6 mph the max label will change to 6 etc... Same thing for the altitude label. So how do I do this?

Comment: Just add a variable(i.e: `currentMaxSpeed`), and each time a change in the speed is detected, just compare it to `currentMaxSpeed`, if it is greater, assign the new value to it.

Comment: What code do I need to do this? like how do I add the variable and assign it. Im sorry for the stupid question but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have either a float or an integer value for your currentSpeed/currentAltitude. Have another set of the same type, (I'll use int for my example) and name them maxSpeed/maxAltitude.

And add this code to the function which updates speed.

```
if(currentSpeed > maxSpeed){
    maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
    maxSpeedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d mph", maxSpeed]; 
}
```

Same goes with altitude.

EDIT: Given your statement: `speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];`

Here is the updated code:

```
float currentSpeed = [location speed] * 2.236936284;
if(currentSpeed - maxSpeed >= 0.01){
        maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
        maxSpeedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f mph", maxSpeed]; 
    }
```

Also, now, currentSpeed and maxSpeed are both floats. Note that I have used a different type of comparison here. Since floats go into a great deal of precision (that we don't always need) I've restricted yours to 2 decimal places. So the text and maxSpeed will only update if it is greater by a factor of 0.01.

Comment: This is actually what I have, its a string, so how do I do it with this?speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a look and tell me if it works for you

Comment: Is that the only code I need for this? and if it is where do i put it?

Comment: Well, no that's not the only code needed. You would need: float maxSpeed, maxAltitude; in your header (.h) file. You would also need to have two new UILabels, maxSpeedLabel and maxAltitudeLabel in the header file. The above code block can be added to the function that updates speed in the implementation file (.m). A similar code block should be added to the function that updates altitude.

Comment: I know that it wouldn't be an IBOutlet, IBAction or -(void) in my header so what is the code that I use in my header. However I do know that I would need an outlet for my max speed label

Comment: and do I have to change the code that I already have for the speed label?

Comment: 1) If you're using Interface Builder, you would need IBOutlet UILabel *maxSpeedLabel, *maxAltitudeLabel; in your header file. 2) You would need to have float maxSpeed, maxAltitude; in your header file. This is to store the numeric values of maxSpeed and maxAltitude. 3) You do not need to change any existing code. Just add my code blocks after your code.

Comment: To float the label do I just say float maxspeedlabel

Comment: What exactly do you mean by float the label? Also, try adding the code where I've suggested. It should work. Set up the maxSpeedLabel and maxAltitudeLabel just like your currentSpeedLabel and currentAltitudeLabel.

Comment: I am going to do that now, but how do i flood max speed in my header file

Comment: And also what is current speed? is that my speed label or just speed?

Comment: currentSpeed is not your label. You label is called speedLabel. currentSpeed is just a numerical value corresponding to the speed returned by your app.

Comment: I coded it and it works perfectly, Thanks! no errors.

Comment: But one quick question, what if I want to have an average speed label?

Comment: How often do you get a new currentSpeed value?

Comment: I get a new current speed value about every second, and I an having a bug. Somethimes the max speed and altitude labels just plain don't work. They will just be blank.

Comment: You have to initialize their text at the start. In viewWillAppear. (or viewDidLoad) maxSpeedLabel.text = @"0 mph"; maxAltitudeLabel.text = @"0 ft";

Comment: I did this in an action that resets the labels and yes the text will reset to 0.00 but the problem is that after the labels reset the actual float does not. So the label will not change from 0.00 until it rises above the max speed that was reached before it was reset to 0.00

Comment: Well then, you have your answer. Change the float values to 0 as well, when you reset.

Comment: How do I do that though, like what do I write and where do I write it. Like I still want them to work the next time around.